# How to communicate back and forth between client and server-side in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Most of my problems in JSF, so far, seem to boil down to this - communication from (static) **client-side** to (dynamic) **server-side**, and vice-versa; for instance, for re-rendering components.

An example: enabling/disabling a button (`commandButton`) that depends on the selection of a `selectoneradio`.

What is the correct way to communicate the selection of the `selectoneradio` (client to server) and then ***ajaxingly*** updating the `commandButton` (server to client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `<f:ajax>`.

Here's an example which enables the button when the second item is selected.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="First item" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Second item" />
    <f:ajax render="button" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:commandButton id="button" disabled="#{bean.selectedItem != 2}" />
```

Make sure that the `#{bean}` is a `@ViewScoped` one so that the state is remembered across postbacks. Else it'll fall back to default values when you press the submit button.

---

That said, I strongly recommend to go through a decent JSF book. The above is usually already covered in 1st chapter.